# Cast object[,] array element to int for conditional operator comparison c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, while-loop, int, type-conversion

I'm attempting to cast object[,] array element to an int for a conditional operator comparison. My classesArray is made up of strings and ints.  The column that i'm referencing can only have a value of 1 or 0, because I am using it for a flag. If there is a 1, I want it to continue to the next line/row. The code i'm using does not execute the program correctly

```
while (classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] == (object)1)
                {
                    classesArrayRow++;
                }
```

and my entire tempArray fills up with the first line of my classesArray. So, i attempted to try

```
while ((int)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] > 0)
```

Although there are no errors, this cast does not work.

My Code:

```
private void ProcessObjects(object[,] classesArray, object[,] classesAvailabilityArray, Excel.Workbook workbook2, Excel.Sheets excelSheets)
    {
        // once classes are selected, they are copied to a temporary location
        // while they're waiting to be printed
        object[,] tempArray = new object[6,3];

        // This stops the while loop once enough credit hours have been taken 
        // if a break condition has not been met first.
        // It must reach 123 hours for CS Degree .
        int hourCounter = 0;

        int iteration = 0;

        while (hourCounter < 123)
        {
            // this while loop copies some classes from classes array to tempArray
            // so they can be printed into the excel template (NewStudentTemplateCS.xlsx)
            //
            int classes = 1, hours = 0; // stops while loop if limit is reached
            int tempArrayRow = 0, tempArrayCol = 0; // used to select individual elements of tempArray
            int classesArrayRow = 1, classesArrayCol = 1; // used to select individual elements of classesArray

            while(classes < 7 || hours < 17)
            {
                // this loop checks the status of the flag and stops at the first avaliable
                // class/row of classesArray
                while (classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] == (object)1)
                {
                    classesArrayRow++;
                }

                // copies the call EX: "MATH 2313" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[tempArrayRow,tempArrayCol] = classesArray[classesArrayRow,classesArrayCol];
                tempArrayCol ++;
                classesArrayCol += 2;
                // copies the name EX: "Calculus I" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[tempArrayRow, tempArrayCol] = classesArray[classesArrayRow, classesArrayCol];
                tempArrayCol++;
                classesArrayCol++;
                // Copies the hours EX: "3" from classesArray to tempArray
                tempArray[tempArrayRow, tempArrayCol] = classesArray[classesArrayRow, classesArrayCol];

                // increments classes, hours, and hourCounter for exit decision
                classes += 1;

                // converts object element to an int for the following "+=" operator
                int numberOfHours = Convert.ToInt32(classesArray[classesArrayRow, classesArrayCol]);

                // adds numberOfHours to the following varriable to increment loop exit decision
                hours += numberOfHours;
                hourCounter += numberOfHours;

                // sets flag to one
                classesArrayCol += 3;
                classesArray[classesArrayRow, classesArrayCol] = 1;

                //reset column varriables
                classesArrayCol = 1;
                tempArrayCol = 0;

                // increments row for temp array
                tempArrayRow++;

            }// end while loop

            // print method that prints temp array and clears tempArray for next use
            PrintArray(tempArray, iteration, workbook2, excelSheets);

            // iterates iteration
            iteration++;

        } // end while loop


    } // end ProcessObjects method
```

My data:

header = call, number, class name, hours, prerequisite number, prerequisite name, and flag. 
Row 1 = MATH 2313, 1000, Calculus I, 3, 0 , 0 , and 0. 
Row 2 = MATH 2113, 1001, Calculus Lab I, 1, 0, 0, and 0

I want to print 
Row 1 = MATH 2113, Calculus I, and 3. 
Row 2 = MATH 2113, Calculus Lab 1, and 1

I filled all null elements with 0s

Comment: Any reason that `classesArray` and `tempArray` are of type `object[,]` and not, say, `int[,]`? In the code your provide, I can't see any reason why you'd use such `object` instead of a more specific type.

Comment: You say there are no errors with the cast, but does not work. Can you be more specific about the non working part?

Comment: @ Albin Sunnanbo - the messagebox reads "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Project.exe

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @ siride This is my first C# project and i'm not familiar with all the commands, data types, and such; so this probably is not the most efficient way to program it. I'm just trying my best to make it work.

Comment: Can explain what do you what to do with this method and what is inside classesArray?

Answer (score 0):

The code `classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] == (object)1` will execute **reference comparison** which should always return false on boxed integers.
The correct way is:

```
while ((int)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] != 0){
    //...
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and received the same error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Project.exe

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @Snuge: It looks like the classesArray[,] containts incorrect data.

Comment: he stated that "My classesArray is made up of strings and ints." you are trying cast string to int

Comment: @lucas: he also said that "The column that i'm referencing can only have a value of 1 or 0, because I am using it for a flag"

Comment: and one of them is false :) @Snuge why do you index form 1 with classesArrayRow?

Comment: I originally intended on leaving all the empty elements blank or null, but i had a problem importing the array from excel that way. I had to fill all the blank elements will a 0 for the import to work correctly. Now 0 means that i have not used that row and 1 means that i have already used the row and I should skip it.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't answer the question. It's indexed from one because excel indexes from one. It just carried over when i imported it.

Comment: @Snuge: Are there null values in classesArray[,7] column?

Comment: I figured out the hard way that classesArray is base 1 and tempArray is base 0

Comment: There are no null values. They have all been filled with zeros.

Comment: @Snuge: Hmm... Which line of code the exactly throws the InvalidCastException? Have you tried to debug this (ensure a check is set in the Debug->Exceptions->CommonLanguage Runtime Exceptions dialog)

Comment: @Snuge did you fill them with 0s in C#? classesArray[i,7] =0;?

Comment: I filled them with 0s in excel before I imported them.

Comment: That may be the problem it could be "0" string not a number.

Comment: @DmitryG I have the CommonLanguage Runtime Exceptions dialog box checked

Comment: @Snuge: I believe the cause of all problems is Excel import code.
Please, ensure that all imported data have been correctly recognised as integers.

Comment: Before iterating the loop, using the code while ((int)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] != 0), classesArray[,7] has a value of "0.0" and is type "object{double}".

Comment: If I type while (classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] != 0), then i get an error "Operator cannot be applied to the operands of type 'object' and 'int'"

Comment: @Snuge: Yeeea ... all clear to me now - if the classesArray[,7] is really **double** you should use the following version of my code:
`(int)(double)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] != 0`

Comment: while ((int)(double)classesArray[classesArrayRow, 7] != 0)                                                                    Still gives me an error

Comment: @Snuge: I believe it's wrong to discuss this further without having the initial data sample. Please edit your question and add a couple the exact data rows used as input (you can copy it from debugger).

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to solve your problem is to write code to check whether is a string or number

```
if(classesArray[0,7] is int) // values were imported as ints
{
    while ((int)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] == 1)
    {
        classesArrayRow++;
    }
}
if(classesArray[0,7] is string) // values were imported as strings
{
    while ((string)classesArray[classesArrayRow,7] == "0")
    {
        classesArrayRow++;
    }
}
```

I would definitely change the whole code, especially when it's not one time task.

Comment: The second if statement partially works. The only problem is all rows of tempArray are filled with the first live of classesArray.